# Map symbols fade after exporting to PDF, JPG, BMP from ArcGIS for DEsktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, jpg, arcgis-10.4

Any solutions how to make the legend symbols not blurry after exporting as an image?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a known issue, and there is a solution for that. Check [Bug: Picture symbol legend patches](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30753), there are some instructions on how to solve this issue from ESRI help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. Some of the images added to the map (or in the style manager) looked like curtains once exported.

I had to use the images in EMF format.